# logstash json filtering not done

Tags: logstash

Here is the sample message:
    {"message":"\u001F\x8B\b\u0000\u0000\tn\x88\u0004\xFFT\x90O\x8F\xD30\u0010ſJ\u0015qc\x9Bz\u001C\x8F\xE3\xE4\xDC\u001E\xF6\x80\x90\xAA\u0015\a.\xD1\xF8\xDF&(\x8EK\xE2\u0016!\xC4wg\xA2E\x82=Y3~\xEF\xF9\xE7\xF7\xABz\x84u\x9B\xF2R\xF5\u0015\xD4P=Uc\xDE\n\u000F\x8F\xC7w\u001E\xB61\xAFeHa\xDB\xE85\xF0\xF6p\xBE\\\x9F\xBF\u0004\u007F\xE8\u000FR\b\u0016\xC4\xFB<\xFFwϛ2\xB1\xBCP\xBAU=\xD4\n\u0011;\x94\x88Z\xC8\xF0QtO\xD5\u001C\u001Ea\xAEz\xCDVr\xD3<\x95\x9F\u001C˶\xC1\xE5\x94h\xF1<\x9D촜\xB6\xF1pt\aK|~\xF8ty\xB9|\xBE\x9E\x87\xF3\xF3\xF5\xB4ޗ\x81n\xB7z\e\xDFLK\xA1i\t\xEB0\xEDN\x84.\xC6V[lu\u0000\u0003\x9Dw\u001E\x85\xB2\u0000>\u0002!\x92C#\xB1i\xBCղѭt\xA8H4$\xB5u!R\u0014\xF6}\xE4Bi\xFFs\xCA\xF7oCJ\xB9\xFC\xC8\xC3^\xD0\xE0\xD6@%\xEC\xEFI\u0001\xFA(\xE4\u0011\xF4\x8Bhz\xECz\u0005\xB5Q\xBCT(ۯ\xBBvJ\\\xDC\e\xDC6\x92D\xDDK\xDFڨ[\u0014\xBA\xB3!:\x83\xAD1\xA4}t\xE8\u0014i\xE5=[\x9BFXF\u0005\xAD\x95\x93\xCA\u0001Xe\x9C\xEDZ\xC3\xDC\xFFR\xFF\xF2A'kЦ\x86\xBAa\u0006!\xC4\xC9\xE5c\xCA+\xD7/ͮ.\xF4ʬ\xD5\xEF?\u0001\u0000\u0000\xFF\xFF\xA7\f(\xFC\xEC\u0001\u0000\u0000","tags":["_jsonparsefailure"],"@version":"1","@timestamp":"2016-02-16T04:00:52.993Z","type":"syslog","host":"192.168.1.34"}

---

Note : "tags":["_jsonparsefailure"],

Config to filter:

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}
```

still i am getting encoded message

EDIT: Adding Logstash Config Files

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5000
    }
    udp {
        port => 5514
#       codec => json
    }
    tcp {
        port => 5516
    }
    syslog {
        port => 1514
    }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
} 

output {
    file {
        path => "/var/log/logstash.log"
    }
    elasticsearch{
        codec => "json"
        hosts => "ls-elasticsearch:9200"
    }
}
```

// Requests are coming on udp port 5514.

Answer (score 0):

if you set your input codec to json, you don't need to set the json filter. You'd be decoding twice.

You are using the json filter on a non json formated field. As the documentation indicates [enter link description here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html), the filter converts the content of a field into data into the logstash event.

Remove the json filter.

Comment: did not solve .. i removed all..  still similar encoding .. looks like some issue with source ..

Comment: Would you mind to share your logstash configuration? I mean: input, filter and output. It would be very useful to see a couple of lines of example data being sent to logstash

Comment: What is your source of events? Could you paste one of your example json inputs?